# Tramp to Windows

Tags: tramp, microsoft-windows

No matter what I try, I can't tramp to Windows;)

I need to turn on debugging, but where does this debug output end up?

All I see is a socket in /tmp when I enable this:

```
;The debug buffer is written as a file in your temporary-file-directory, which is usually /tmp/. 
(customize-set-variable 'tramp-debug-to-file t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Tramp's own manual, you will find a section about setting `tramp-verbose`, titled `9 How to Customize Traces`. You can find it by typing <kbd>C-h i</kbd>, select `Tramp`, then `Traces and Profiles`.

As explained there, with a value greater than `4`, messages will be logged to a specific buffer you could check.

Comment: yes, I've already (setq tramp-verbose 10), but I want this logged to a file that I can follow

Comment: Isn't it enough to enable `auto-revert-tail-mode` on TRAMP's buffer for that? [Note: I am not a TRAMP expert.]

Comment: Have you set `tramp-debug-to-file` before you have set `tramp-verbose`, and before you've tried to access the remote machine?

Comment: Another point: `tramp-debug-to-file` exist since Tramp 2.5 (Emacs 28). So you must run either a recent Emacs, or install a recent Tramp version from GNU ELPA.